# React-native DrawerNavigator does not show up

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to create simple DrawerNavigator. But it does not show up :(

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer, createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class One extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<Text>One</Text>);
    }
}

class Two extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<Text>Two</Text>);
    }
}

const DrawerStack = createDrawerNavigator(
    {
        One: {screen: One},
        Two: {screen: Two},
    }, {
    }
);

const App = createAppContainer(DrawerStack);
export default App;
```

This is what I see (no drawer navigation is displayed):

[image: no drawer navigator]

Answer (score 2):

1. Swipe from the left and you will see the drawerNavigation works
2. the react-navigation createDrawerNavigator does not provide stack navigation by default, if you are looking to see a header with the menu icon, then you have to make your screens (one, two) be stackNavigation.

   NB: import Icon from expo or react-native-icons

**Updated:: using native-base**

1. install native-base ( ** npm install native-base  --save** )
2. import Header, Icon, Container, Left, Content from native-base

   class One extends Component {

   ```
   render() {
       return (
             <Container>
                 <Header>
                   <Left>
                     <Icon name="md-menu" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()} />
                   </Left>
                 </Header>

                 <Content>
                   <Text>Screen One</Text>
                 </Content>
             </Container>
         );
   }
   ```

   }

   class Two extends Component {

   ```
   render() {
        return (
             <Container>
                 <Header>
                   <Left>
                     <Icon name="md-menu" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()} />
                   </Left>
                 </Header>

                 <Content>
                   <Text>Screen Two</Text>
                 </Content>
             </Container>
         );
   }
   ```

   }

   const DrawerStack = createDrawerNavigator(
     {
        one:{screen:One},
        two: {screen: Two}
     }, {

   }
   );

[image: Drawer]
[image: Screen One]
[image: Screen Two]

Comment: 1. Swiping from the left does not work for me (Android).

2. It works, but only for screenOne. Do I need to add createStackNavigator for every screen as well (Two, Three, Four, ...) ? If there is a way to have this code added only once for all screens ?

Comment: @Alex I have updated the code using native base and it much simpler. Try it out and let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Drawer Swipe Gesture is not working because in the new version of react navigation v3 npm. We need to install [react-native-gesture-handler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gesture-handler/v/1.0.0-alpha.34?activeTab=readme) npm separately. They create separated npm package for touch & gesture handling and recognition.

Step 1.

```
npm i react-native-gesture-handler
```

Step 2.

```
react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
```

Step 3.(optional )

If step 2 is not worked properly, code is confogured properly

To finalize the installation of react-native-gesture-handler for Android, be sure to make the necessary modifications to MainActivity.java:

```
package com.reactnavigation.example;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
+ import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
+ import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
+ import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "Example";
  }

+  @Override
+  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
+    return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
+      @Override
+      protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
+       return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
+      }
+    };
+  }
}
```

No additional steps are required for iOS.

Please Refer the following document for more information:-

1. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html#installation
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gesture-handler/v/1.0.0-alpha.34?activeTab=readme
3. https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Step 3 - this is what I needed. I already installed and linked react-native link, but Step 3 was missing in my case.

Comment: Some time react-native link react-native-gesture-handler command is not worked properly that why we need to manually configure code if step 2 working properly there is no need of step 3

Answer (score 0):

It's  good to take advantage of the native base.

The relevant link is [here.](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink)

The navigation links are [here.](https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/examples/navigation/StackNavigationExample.html)

You can also see the component here, so you can use the features you need.

Drawer navigation example.js:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import HomeScreen from "./HomeScreen.js";
import MainScreenNavigator from "../ChatScreen/index.js";
import Profile from "../ProfileScreen/index.js";
import SideBar from "../SideBar/SideBar.js";
import { DrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";
const HomeScreenRouter = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Chat: { screen: MainScreenNavigator },
    Profile: { screen: Profile }
  },
  {
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />
  }
);
export default HomeScreenRouter;
```

[image]

Easy to operate without special implementation.

If you have any further comments, please leave a comment.
And if my answer is good, please make a choice.